# UIWebview with multiple Youtube video's, get notification of which one is playing

Tags: ios, video, uiwebview, youtube, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a webview with content, which can contain multiple youtube video's. When the user starts a video, I want to know which one this is.

I know I can get a notification when a video is started with `UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification` and I can find out youtube URL from HTML in the webview, but how can I found out which one is playing, when there are two or more?

Maybe there's some way to get the MediaPlayer and find out which URL is currently playing or something?

Answer (score 1):

The only way u can contact with `UIWebView` is via `javaScript` bridge.

I'll explain:

The `UIWebView` doesn't know what u r showing inside, is pretty much a generic `UIWebView` that can either show list or simple `html` content.

To solve your problem you should build a simple bridge (JS-IOS):

JS->IOS:

In the `javascript` when the user click on the video list cell, perform

```
window.location = "cellSelected=2";
```

And the UIWebViewDelegate will fire

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

Then, u can parse the `request.url`

IOS->JS:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"your javascript code string here"];
```

Hope that will give u first kick to solve your problem.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `contentURL` which is a property of MPMoviePlayerController instance?

As mentioned by Apple:
[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMoviePlayerController/contentURL)